# how to run Rstudio on a computation node of a remote linux cluster

Tags: rstudio, remote-server

I have a heavy job of R script and want to run in Rstudio. Surely I can login the remote cluster and use `qsub -I` to get in a computation node and run the script interactively, but I am wondering, is there anyway to do it with Rstudio (since Rstudio is such a great tool)?

Answer (score 1):

What is often done is use Rstudio for development and then wrap everything in a self-contained R script to submit to the cluster with something like

```
#! /bin/bash
## Submission options
R CMD BATCH --save script.R output.log
```

Alternatively, you can submit your job to PBS/SGE/... from withing Rstudio using [Batchjob](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BatchJobs/index.html). See for instance the minimal example reproduced [from the manual](https://github.com/tudo-r/BatchJobs/blob/master/examples/minimal.R).

```
library("BatchJobs")

f <- function(data) {
  if (data > 4) {
    Sys.sleep(100*data)
  }
  -data
}

## Create simple registry:
reg <- makeRegistry(id="minimal", file.dir="minimal")
batchMap(reg, f, 1:20)

## Submit jobs:
submitJobs(reg)

## Collect (partial) results:
res <- reduceResults(reg, fun=function(aggr, job, res) c(aggr, res))
print(res)
```

If you are pleased with this solution, you can go to the next level with [Batchexperiments](https://github.com/tudo-r/Batchexperiments)